# PointsToLine Failed to execute

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, error-999999, points-to-line

Using [this article](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011815) as a guide, I've been trying to connect points to the nearest location on a line road feature class. This works until the last step, the Points To Line tool. It consistently gives a runtime error 999999: Error executing function.

999999 errors don't really tell me what's going wrong. This has occurred on different machines. On opening the script for the tool, it imports arcpy, os and types. Not familiar with the types module. It also has the lines

> if **name** == '**main**':
>       convertPoints()

although I don't see the main function anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Not trying to rewrite the code in the existing script for PointsToLine in ArcToolbox. Just included that as a possible clue.  I don't know the spefic cause of the error, that's what I'm asking, along with any fixes.